# Correctly handling errors from a Database Transaction in your Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I have a method called `invite!` in my user model which will generate a unique token for a user and email them an invitation to join / sign up for my app.

The simplified implementation is -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  # ...

  def invite!
    transaction do
      generate_invitation_token
      mark_as_invited
      save!
    end

    WelcomeMailer.delay.send_invitation(id)
  end
end
```

As you can see, it does some setup steps inside a transaction and then sends a `WelcomeMailer` invitation.

The key here is that I do NOT want an email delivered if there is any issue in updating the database during the transaction.

How do I best implement some error handling here?

1. The ruby-level method could throw an error. For example `save!` might error because of some model validation. In that case I can `rescue` it and `return` before it gets to the mailer.
2. What happens if there's some DB level transaction that errors out? Does it bubble up and throw an error in ruby? Will the same `begin..rescue` approach work there as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two points about your case:

- "RecordInvalid - raised by ActiveRecord::Base#save! and ActiveRecord::Base.create! when the record is invalid." ([link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html))
- "Also have in mind that exceptions thrown within a transaction block will be propagated (after triggering the ROLLBACK), so you should be ready to catch those in your application code." ([link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html))

That means, what in a case of an error inside the transaction block in your current simplified code next things will happen:

- the transaction will be rolled back
- a mail will not be sent
- the error will be throwed upper from `invite!`

If it's necessary to make some actions in a case of an error inside the transaction block, you may change the code like this:

```
def invite!
  transaction do
    generate_invitation_token
    mark_as_invited
    save!
  end
rescue RecordInvalid => e
  # some actions 
  raise e
else
  # code that runs only if *no* exception was raised
  WelcomeMailer.delay.send_invitation(id)
end
```